# Thumbnails das Categorias

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

qual seria melhor forma de pegar o thumbnails das categorias ?

```
function get_listaCatPort($atts) {
 echo '<ul class="section section-filters">';
                                $atts = array(
                                        'taxonomy'              => 'portfolio-types',
                                        'orderby'               => 'name',
                                        'order'                 => 'ASC',
                                        'show_count'            => 0,
                                        'hierarchical'          => 1,
                                        'hide_empty'            => 1,
                                        'title_li'              => '',
                                        'depth'                 => 1,
                                        'walker'                => new New_Walker_Category(),
                                        'current_category'      => get_queried_object()->term_id,
                                        );
                                wp_list_categories($atts);
                echo '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode('listaCatPortfolio', 'get_listaCatPort');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala parceiro, tudo beleza?

Cara, eu consigo fazer o que você quer com o plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

Basicamente, eu crio um campo personalizado de imagem e depois defino a localização dele, durante a configuração do mesmo, para aparecer na página de edição do grupo de "taxonomy" que eu quero.

Feito isso, vou para a parte da codificação no template, com objetivo de exibir a thumb da categoria.

Então faço:

```
<div>
    <?php
        $tags = get_terms('MINHA_TAXONOMY');
        $post_tags = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'MINHA_TAXONOMY',array('fields' => 'slugs'));
    ?>
    <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ): ?>

    <?php
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'MINHA_TAXONOMY');
        $variable = 'categoria_'. $terms;
        $attachment_id = get_field('NOME_DO_MEU_CAMPO_IMAGEM', $variable);
        $size = "full"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
        $ID = $tag->term_id;
        $term_id = $ID;
        $image = get_field('NOME_DO_MEU_CAMPO_IMAGEM', 'category_'. $term_id); 
    ?>

    <div>
        <a href="#" class="block <?php echo $tag->slug; ?>">       
        <?php if ( $image ) : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
        <?php else : ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/no-picture.jpg">
        <?php endif; ?>   
        <span><?php echo $tag->name ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</div>
```

Então, nas definições, você terá que editar em **"MINHA_TAXONOMY"** e **"NOME_DO_MEU_CAMPO_IMAGEM"**, de acordo com os seus dados.

Se você já mexe com o plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), vai entender um pouco do que eu botei acima. Caso contrário, recomendo você dar uma estudada na documentação dele. O plugin é genial!

Espero que te ajude!

Abraço.

Comment: hummmm cara realmente, havia usado esse plugin no passado em outra situação, realmente faz sentido o que tu disse, vou tentar aqui. Obrigado pela dica aí irmão!!!

Comment: Beleza! Nesse meu caso aí, eu exibo no tema uma listagem das categorias que tenho.

Comment: Brício, no só veja se estou no caminho certo, por favor:
1º - crio um campo  do Tipo Imagem
2ª - Localização, crio a Regras que seria tipo "Taxonomia = Categoria de Porfólios" ?

Comment: deu certinho aqui irmão, valeu demais aí pelas dicas. ;)

Comment: Show cara, que bom! Note que você ainda pode descartar algumas variáveis, caso queira deixar o código mais limpo.

Comment: sim, vi isso mesmo, muito bom. Esse plugin da infinitas possibilidades, já estou usando pra outra ideia aqui hehehe.

Comment: cara, percebi uma coisa. Quando uso: 
    $image = get_field('capa_cat', 'category_' .$tag->term_id);     
    
    funciona lindo, porém se eu clicar em editar página, ele fica 
    carregando até travar. Será que esqueci de algo, ou to fazendo errado ?

Comment: Editar página no seu admin do wordpress?

Comment: isso, tipo na página ou post que eu adicionar esse shortcode que criei, se eu tento edita-la ele fica carregando até dar erro 502 ou 505, aí testei. Então, aí eu vou lá no meu arquivo functions.php e comento essa linha do $image no meu shortcode, aí ele não trava mais, porém não me lista minhas imagens kkkkk

Comment: Certo! Cara, esse código que te passei você adiciona no próprio tema, no local exato que deseja exibir, nada deve ser inserido na functions.php

Comment: ah ok vou fazer isso então, 
Obrigado!!!

Comment: Irmão, só mais um questão. Estou tentando não mostrar algumas categorias, em específico porém acho que estou usando de forma errada o 
'category__not_in' => array( '12', '13')  .

Comment: Tenta usar o 'exclude' => '12', '13' .... ou então  'exclude' => array( '12', '13'). Não lembro bem se é um ou outro.